# Getting failed to open stream: HTTP request failed error with names with symboles

Tags: php, string, echo

Why I got this error :

> failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found

Code :

```
$Name = 'Teàst';
$result = file_get_contents('http://example.com/name/' . $Name . );
```

But when I try `echo $result;` I got the link and its work fine.
And when I try `$Name = 'Teast';` (without "à" symbole) its work fine.
Soo the problem is names with symboles (é è à ...).
How to fix it please ?

Answer (score 0):

Use  htmlspecialchars method,

```
 $Name = 'Teàst';
    $result = file_get_contents('http://example.com/name/' . htmlspecialchars($Name));
```

Comment: But my result contains the name and i can't execute the rest of my code when the name is changed to `teÃ st` in the result

Answer (score 0):

use

[htmlspecialchars()](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars)

```
$Name = 'Teàst';
$Name =htmlspecialchars($Name);
$result = file_get_contents('http://example.com/name/' .$Name);
```

Comment: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request

Answer (score 0):

This code works for me:

```
<?php
$Name = 'Teàst';
$result = file_get_contents('http://example.com/name/' . $Name );
echo $result
?>
```

And this code works:

```
<?php

$Name = 'Teàst';
$Name = htmlspecialchars($Name);
$result = file_get_contents('http://localhost/temp/' . $Name);

echo $result
?>
```

Comment: @vladeuurs255s you got some advance with your problem?